# HTTPS 443 not accessible to the outside world DOCKER

Tags: ubuntu, docker, xampp

Currently I have setup

`docker` with `linux ubuntu 18.04`

In my container `reverent_ptolemy`

contains the project of my api.

On my container

HTTP vhosts configuration is listening to `3021`

HTTPS vhosts configuration is listening to `1250`

and on my Host

port `3021` is mapped to port `80`

port `1250` is mapped to port `443`

[image]

In my `host` docker

I can access my api through `HTTPS Curl`

like this

`curl https://<sub-domain>/api/login`

[image]

But when I tried to access this from the browser

this gives me an error like this

[image]

PS:

Only `http://<subdomain>/api/login` is *accessible from the outside world* not the `https`

What could be the reason why HTTPS is only accessible on the host and container but not accessible from the outside world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

First if you're trying to do SSL on your docker. Make sure your `443` port is forwarded. You may check your 443 port if it is open or closed

here : https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 0):

First of all check iptables (if you allow https traffic) or directly add a rule on the fly (will not be available after reboot or iptables restart - this is just for test sake):

`iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

Secondly, you were trying to use GET method for your API when most likely it only allows POST method.